# Number of solutions to infinite sum of polynomial equation

Tags: real-analysis

How many solutions (at most) are there in the following equation?

$a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\cdots=0$, where each $a_i\in\mathbb{R}$, and $x\in (0,1)$?

Is it possible to find some $\underline{x}\in (0,1) $, such that all $x\geq \underline{x}$ are the solutions to the above equation?

I know that the fundamental theorem of algebra tells us that there are $n$ solutions for the $n$ degree polynomial, but don't know that happens when $n$ is infinity.

Comment: What about identity?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score -1):

The theorem only says there can be ATMOST n solutions for n degree polynomial. There could be much less. As your equation ends with $=0$, the no. of solutions can be given by the number of  indivisible factors of your polynomial; if there are no factors, there is 1 solution (not necessary a real no.).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question in on infinite polynomials.

Comment: I have answered the question for infinite polynomials only. If there is some repetitive pattern based on which the ENTIRE polynomial can be factorized into 2 (or more) finite or infinte polynomials, the no. of solutions is equal to the number of factors. If there is no such factorization (if a0, a1, a2, etc. are random numbers), then there is only 1 unique solution.